# Confirmed regression in behavior of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths on iOS 9.1 only?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard, ios9.1

I have an app that supports iOS 7.1 and higher.  When an user selects a cell and makes a field change on a detail view the tableView row will be reloaded to reflect the change upon navigating back.   There are several autolayout constraints on this cell in its storyboard.  The cell contains only 9 UILabels but with varying point sizes of non-default fonts.

Row updating is verified working correctly on devices running iOS 7.1.2, 8.4.1, and 9.0.2.  In addition I have tested it working in the simulator for 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3.   But if fails on 9.1 with users reporting this since the iOS update came out. It fails for both device and simulator.

The failure is a loss of storyboard autolayout constraints for the entire cell.  All of the cell labels overwrite each other in a jumble after calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths for only the updated row.  The problem with the one cell persists until reloading the entire table again from core data (pull to refresh).  At which point it will have the updated value the user did.

To work around this I have done the following to the call:

```
// work around cell layout bug introduced with iOS 9.1
  if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0.3"))
      [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Which is just a version check macro.  This code is called within viewWillAppear of the tableView after the user navigates back from the detail view having made their value change.  This workaround avoids the problem.

To insure we can do this reload before we lose the value, the beginning of viewWillAppear has also always had these lines:

```
// we need to save this before the super clears it
NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[super viewWillAppear: animated];
```

The app is built with Xcode 7.1 using storyboard and size classes. The problem remains with Xcode 7.1.1 as well.  Usage is within a UITableViewController.

Just me or anyone else seen this change in behavior?

Comment: I could only find this which appeared like it might be related https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/6623

Comment: This defect still persists in the 9.2 update